# How to force insert/update with server timezone when using now() function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I build a table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE timestamp_demo (userid varchar,ts TIMESTAMP,tstz TIMESTAMPTZ);
```

I set my computer(client) timezone into "Asia/Taipei" and insert a record.

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_demo (userid, ts, tstz) values('UTC+8',now(),now());
```

And check the result.

```
select * from timestamp_demo;

userid:UTC+8 / ts:2022-04-21 11:14:27 / tstz: 2022-04-21 11:14:27
```

Set my computer(client) timezone into "Europe/London" and insert a record.

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_demo (userid, ts, tstz) values('UTC',now(),now());
```

And check the result again.

```
select * from timestamp_demo;

userid:UTC+8 / ts:2022-04-21 11:14:27 / tstz: 2022-04-21 03:14:27
userid:UTC / ts:2022-04-21 03:15:27 / tstz: 2022-04-21 03:15:27
```

Seems PostgreSQL would auto transfer datetime into the timezone in client.

But I would like to process transfer datetime timezone on UI instead on PostgreSQL.

And no matter what timezone setting in the client.

When using now() function, it can return server time instead client time.

In other words, if my server timezone is "Asia/Taipei" and client timezone is "Europe/London", then when I type now() function in the client side, it could return Taipei time instead London
time just like Oracle.

Is there anyway to do this?

Here is my PostgreSQL version:

PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

And I use DBeaver 21.2.0 as client.

Comment: What client are you using? Just don't make it set the timezone for the connection.

Comment: I'm not believing your results. The `tstz` values should have a timezone included. What version of Postgres are using? And where did you install it from? Add answer as update to your question.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver , Just updated the server/client content in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions. One is to specify the time zone for `now()` in the INSERT query. The other is to set a default value in the column definition.
***SPECIFY TIMEZONE IN THE INSERT***
We specify the timezone for each insert. This is independent of client and server time settings.

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_demo (userid, ts, tstz) values
('-6',now(),now() at time zone 'utc-6'),
( '0',now(),now() at time zone 'utc'  ),
('+6',now(),now() at time zone 'utc+6');
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM timestamp_demo;
> ```
>
> ```
> userid | ts                         | tstz                         
> :----- | :------------------------- | :----------------------------
> -6     | 2022-04-21 07:23:53.934306 | 2022-04-21 12:23:53.934306+01
> 0      | 2022-04-21 07:23:53.934306 | 2022-04-21 06:23:53.934306+01
> +6     | 2022-04-21 07:23:53.934306 | 2022-04-21 00:23:53.934306+01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cb0d1c52a74b83ee75a9af54eba4fd8b)*

***DEFAULT VALUES***

The other solution is to specify `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the column definition, and leave the column out of the field list when you insert. The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will therefore be calculated on the server.

```
CREATE TABLE timestamp_demo (
  userid varchar,
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  tstz TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```